# Sensor Pose is wrong

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I am having trouble with ray sensors and their pose in gazebo 1.4. The pose of links can be handled like I want them to behave. So I fixed my problem by using an extra link for each sensor until now.

```
 <link name="link_sensor1">
    <pose>0.0 0.0 0.51 0.0 0.0 0.0</pose>
    <sensor name="raysensor" type="ray">
     <always_on>true</always_on>
     <visualize>true</visualize>
     <ray>
      <!--...-->
     </ray>
    </sensor>
  </link>
  <link name="link_sensor2">
    <pose>0.0 0.0 0.51 0.0 -1.57 0.0 </pose>
    <sensor name="raysensor2" type="ray">
      <always_on>true</always_on>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
      <ray>
       <!--...-->
      </ray>
    </sensor>
  </link>
```

Now I want to add all the sensors to one link, to have an easier control via joints (I don't want to add a seperate joint for each sensor)

The model:

```
<model name="box">
  <pose>0 0 0.5 0 0 0</pose>
  <static>false</static>
  <link name="link">
    <inertial>
      <mass>1.0</mass>
      <inertia>
        <ixx>1.0</ixx>
        <ixy>0.0</ixy>
        <ixz>0.0</ixz>
        <iyy>1.0</iyy>
        <iyz>0.0</iyz>
        <izz>1.0</izz>
      </inertia>
    </inertial>
    <collision name="collision">
      <geometry>
        <box>
          <size>1 1 1</size>
        </box>
      </geometry>
     </collision>
    <visual name="collision">
      <geometry>
        <box>
          <size>1 1 1</size>
        </box>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>
  <link name="link2">
    <sensor name="raysensor" type="ray">
      <always_on>true</always_on>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
      <pose>0.0 0.0 0.51 0.0 0.0 0.0</pose>
      <ray>
        ...
      </ray>
    </sensor>
    <sensor name="raysensor2" type="ray">
      <always_on>true</always_on>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
      <pose>0.0 0.0 0.51 0.0 -1.57 0.0 </pose>
      <ray>
       ...
      </ray>
    </sensor>
  </link>
  <joint name="my_joint" type="revolute">
    <parent>link</parent>
    <child>link2</child>
    <axis>
      <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
    </axis>
  </joint>
</model>
```

In gazebo there is the following result:
[image: image description]

I don't get any rotation done correctly... What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help me please...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3598/sensor-pose-is-wrong/) by [Chris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/269/chris/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 67 on 2013-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

yes there was a bug in laser visualization in gazebo 1.4 but the actual laser range values may be correct. If you installed from source, you can manually apply the [patch](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/599/fix-laser-visual-rotation/diff). Alternatively, update to the latest revision of default branch.

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2013-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/269/chris/) on 2013-07-17**:
Thanks for your answer. It helped partly. See my second post